# Pandas - groupby, aggregate and scale on the sum of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'A': [2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]})
df
Out[253]: 
   id  A  B
0   1  2  1
1   2  2  2
2   2  3  1
3   3  3  3
4   3  5  2
5   3  2  4
```

I'd like to `groupby` `'id'`, and aggregate using a `sum` function over `'A'`, `'B'`. But I'd also like to scale A and B by the sum of `A+B` (per each 'id), So the following output will look as follows:

```
   id         A         B
0   1  0.666667  0.333333
1   2  0.625000  0.375000
2   3  0.526316  0.473684
```

Now, I can do

```
res = df.groupby('id').agg('sum').reset_index()
scaler = res['A'] + res['B']
res['A'] /= scaler
res['B'] /= scaler
res
Out[275]: 
   id         A         B
0   1  0.666667  0.333333
1   2  0.625000  0.375000
2   3  0.526316  0.473684
```

Which is quite **inelegant**. Is there a way to put all this "scalar" logic in the aggregation function ? Or any other pythonic and elegant way to do it? Solutions involving `numpy` are also welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use `agg` function for scaling, because working with each column separately.

Solution is remove `reset_index` for alignment in division ([`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)) of `Series` created by `sum`:

```
res = df.groupby('id').sum()
res = res.div(res.sum(axis=1), axis=0).reset_index()
print (res)
   id         A         B
0   1  0.666667  0.333333
1   2  0.625000  0.375000
2   3  0.526316  0.473684
```

Details:

```
print (res.sum(axis=1))
id
1     3
2     8
3    19
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `sum` along the first axis:

```
res = df.groupby('id').agg('sum')
res.div(res.sum(1), 0)
```

```
           A         B
id
1   0.666667  0.333333
2   0.625000  0.375000
3   0.526316  0.473684
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
In [584]: res = df.groupby('id').sum()

In [585]: res.div(res.sum(1), 0).reset_index()
Out[585]:
   id         A         B
0   1  0.666667  0.333333
1   2  0.625000  0.375000
2   3  0.526316  0.473684
```